# Automation Framework recommendations

Tags: automation, frameworks

I am in search of an open source test automation framework. I have to test :

1. React based UI
2. Rest APIs
3. Big Data Validation which is done using Pyspark

I have read through few frameworks like Serenity BDD, Sentinel, TestProject.io, Robot Framework.
But I was looking at something that could integrate Python and Java together. Or would it be wise to use one framework for data validation with Python and another for UI and API.

Looking forward to your inputs.

TIA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.